# When did you use @RequestBody and @Pathvariable and @RequestParam

Tags: spring-boot, rest, servlets, resttemplate

I have some application using Micro service architecture in Spring boot. I have send the query parameter, Object, Model and etc using @PathVariable in RestTemplate. After developed the application, I did some research and there are asked to use @RequestParam and @RequestBody. But I can't uanble to understand and also I don't know how to use @RequestBody and @RequestParam. What are benefits while using @RequestBody instead of @PathVariable.

I have send the GET request using Spring boot RestTemplate.

Answer (score 2):

In short, Path variable and request params will be part of the URL and the request body will be part of body of the request.

When you want to locate a resource then go for @PathVariable i.e. fetch/delete a user by id.

```
/users/{id}
```

When you want to query/search/filter the data then go for query parameters.

```
users?lastName=abc
```

When you want to save a user then go for request body.

```
{
"username" : "abc",
"email" : "abc@gmail.com"
}
```